# How should I handle a db connection in Javascript / AWS Lambda

Tags: javascript, mysql, amazon-web-services, lambda

In my JS Lambda function I have something along the lines of the following...

```
import utils from './utils'

index.handler() {
  return utils.initDB()
  .then(function() {
    return utils.doSomething()
```

utils.js:

```
var dbConfig = null;
var knex = null;

function initDB() {
  dbConfig = require('../db');
  knex = require('knex')(dbConfig);
  return;
}
```

Basically, how should I pass around the `knex` object? Is it okay to have as a global var in the utils file? Should I return it to the handler and pass it into every `smsUtils.doX` call? I'm thinking this might be causing problems with db connection/pooling, but I don't know how to find out.

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who stumbles on this in the future (i.e. me when I'm googling how to do this again in a year):

http://blog.rowanudell.com/database-connections-in-lambda/ explains connection reuse in Lambda. Should look something like this:

```
const pg = require('pg');

const client = new pg.Client('postgres://myrds:5432/dbname');  
client.connect();

exports.handler = (event, context, cb) => {  
  client.query('SELECT * FROM users WHERE ', (err, users) => {
    // Do stuff with users
    cb(null); // Finish the function cleanly
  });
};
```